# Worker thread and main thread difference, update to UI?

Tags: android

I have understood that the CountDownTimer will always run on UI thread(Main thread) and "Thread" class runs in the background. Can I update anything in the UI using "Thread" class?

What i want to learn is how to separate background thread from main thread. I am thinking of this because the app is sluggish when I use, so I want to move few of the calculations to the background.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *I am confused here that, the countdown timer runs on a ui thread (main thread) and the "Thread" runs as a worker thread*, what does confuse you?  *Is it the way to create a background thread?* it is one way

Comment: Pay attention that you are modifying UI elements on background Thread when using Toast, and that will give you an exception.

Comment: hi if you want  to run a background task will not affecting the UI  you can use asynctask for this and at the end of the task you can update the UI            lock at this reference https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html                i hope this helps you

Comment: Hi guys, Thank you so much it helped me.